# How to write a event_before_delete trigger on joomla model?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.1

I have two models

1. Gallery
2. Image

While deleting Gallery I want to delete the associated Image records ans images in directory  and then delete Gallery object and directory .

The best choice seems to be onBeforeContentDelete trigger, for which I have to write a plugin. But do  not want to go through all plugin creation steps.

Is it possible to delete this way ?

```
class SomePrefixModelGallery extends JModelAdmin
{
    public function __construct($config=array())
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    public function onBeforeGalleryDelete($context,$table){
        if( $this->deleteAllImages()){
           $this->removeDir($this->folder);
          return true;
         }
        else
         return false;
    }

    public function deleteAllImages(){
       // get Image model and delete all images 
    }
}
```

Going through JModelAdmin core class I can see that in `config` array event name could be passed e.g

```
 `array('event_before_delete'=>'onXYZEventName')`
```

The default event set is `onBeforeContentDelete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's your own component you can just override the delete method in your model, you don't need a plugin.

`JModelAdmin` has a `delete()` method, so in your Model:

```php
class SomePrefixModelGallery extends JModelAdmin
{
      /* all the standard methods */

     /**
      * Method to delete one or more records.
      *
      * @param   array  &$pks  An array of record primary keys.
      *
      * @return  boolean  True if successful, false if an error occurs.
      *
      * @since   11.1
      */
     public function delete(&$pks)
     {
        // Code to delete your image records

        // Code to delete your image files

        // Call the parent delete to remove the Gallery entry
        parent::delete(&$pks);
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks I did manage to do this way. But I was in search to manage through event. It seem I have to write a content plugin for my component and respective model to handle this through events